# any difference here?

Tags: grammar

I need you guys' help.

"Many teenagers spend too much time sitting and **a lack of physical activity** leads to excess calories accumulating in the body."

What if I write **"lack of physical activity"**

Is there any difference with **"a"** in meaning?

Comment: No difference.  Either if perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Another possibility is "the lack etc."

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I agree that there is no real difference in meaning.   Both are correct grammatically. However,  I think that most people would NOT say "a" .   It is a smoother and more flowing without the "a".